# Function or method as value in collection

Tags: hacklang

Is it possible to pass a function or method call as value in a collection of any type?

```
$collection = Vector {
    function(){}
};
```

The code above throws Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, this looks like a limitation of the HHVM parser. Below are a few options for working around it using locals. Feel free to [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) to support the literal syntax in your original question if it's important to you.

Option 1:

```
$v = Vector {};
$f = function () {};
$v[] = $f;
```

Option 2:

```
$f = function () {};
$v = Vector {$f};
```

etc.